# Performance issues when using CMOS SR Latch with 180nm transistor models in circuit simulator

Tags: transistors, simulation, logic-gates, cmos, spice

I am trying to incorporate a CMOS SR latch made with 180nm Level +49 transistors into a larger circuit but am running into issues. I am hoping this community can point me in the right direction of possible solutions.

First, I made a CMOS NOR gate with the transistor model in xyce (an open source circuit simulator) and built them into an SR latch. I was able to get the NOR gate and SR latch working, or so it seems. I used the following configuration *exactly* as shown.

[image: CMOS NOR GATE]

This is the SR latch behavior for the SR latch I built with the transistors:
(I am using matlab to read the csv outputs)..

V(2) is RESET, V(3) is SET, V(4) is Q
[image: SR latch CMOS]

And this is the behavior for a xyce SR latch built with ideal NOR gates

[image: SR ideal]
(not a fast pullup time but decent enough); note: These simulations are about 300ms long

I also want to include some parameters I am using for the SR latch made with ideal NOR gates in case they ring a bell for anyone..

```
    * Ideal NOR gate default parameters:

.param R1HI=5 R1LO=200 R0HI=200 R0LO=5 RIN=1000 R1=100

.param SW=5.e-9  CAPOUT=1.e-12  CAPIN=1.e-12



*SR Latch Digital model card

.model DMOD DIG ( CLO=CAPOUT  CHI=CAPOUT

+ S0RLO=R0LO  S0RHI=R0HI  S0TSW=SW

+ S0VLO=-1  S0VHI=1.1 ;logic margins LOW               

+ S1RLO=R1LO  S1RHI=R1HI  S1TSW=SW

+ S1VLO=1.7  S1VHI=1.9  ;logic margins HIGH                                            

+ RLOAD=RIN   CLOAD=CAPIN

+ DELAY=2ns )
```

I built these and tested them in separate files even using the same node names.

However, when I incorporated them into the larger circuit, the ideal SR latch worked in unison with the larger circuit as expected, but the CMOS latch had erratic behavior with no distinguishable pattern. The simulator still generated output but the behavior was not at all what was expected. The CMOS SR latch stopped resembling an SR latch, as far as I can tell. This is strange because they both had pretty much identical behavior in their respective simuations (save for the pullup time on the ideal latch).

- Are there any modifications to the CMOS circuit that could resolve an issue like this?
- What test could I perform on the SR latch, nor gate, or nmos/pmos transistor to see what is causing this difference in behavior?
- Kind of following up on the first bullet point, when building gates out of transistor models like these, should I include external resistances/capacitances/etc to eliminate possible strange behavior? etc

Any help appreciated! I will do my best to clear up questions if there are any.

Comment: Re-sim this with 1GigaHertz clocks. The rise-fall times should then be visible, and any glitches become more apparent.

Comment: Your plots are very difficult to interpret. Please expand the time scale to show just two or three cycles, and use a proper time axis. If possible, separate the signals vertically so they don't overlap.

Comment: Spice-based transient simulations usually don't have a fixed timestep. Plotting "samples" on the X-axis may not tell you anything about rise and fall times! Read the "time"-signal from the CSV file and use that as the x-coordinates instead.

Comment: My first guess for your problem is instability, but it's hard to tell given your info. The propagation time of the cmos nor-based latch appears (can't be sure without a propert time-axis) much lower than the ideal nor-based latch, which may be a possible trigger for that.